# default link color stay's active until mouse click on another link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the default link color active when you enter the site but I can't seem to get it to remove off active when mouse clicks on another link and the new current page is now active. here is my code.

JS

```
$("a").on("click", function() { 
    $(".active").removeClass("active"); 
});
```

CSS

```
.active{ 
    color: #ffff00 
    !important; 
}

a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    z-index: 5; 
    font-family: arial, "Trebuchet MS"; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    color: #2777A3; 
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.pro.com/" target="_self" class="active">Home</a>`
```

[image: home page active by default but when clicked on another link, new link does not show active color]

Comment: Is the "new current page" loaded with AJAX or does the page refresh?

Comment: have you used tried using ':visited' ?

Comment: @tracy, no, don't know ajax and @ eric, no

Comment: to clarify, you want to toggle the link colors? for example, if you click products, home should be white and products should turn yellow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have HTML, CSS, and JQuery, you just need to set the `active` class on the right link on each page. You don't need to remove classes with JQuery.

What seems to be happening is that when a user clicks on a link, the page reloads, which resets the CSS and puts the `active` class on the `Home` link again. Every time the user clicks, the page will refresh and reset the class.

So, JQuery will effectively remove the class, but then clicking on the link will send the browser to the new page and reset the CSS.

Example:

Home

```
<a href="http://www.pro.com/" target="_self" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="http://www.pro.com/products" target="_self">Products</a>
<a href="http://www.pro.com/solutions" target="_self">Solutions</a>
```

Other Page 1

```
<a href="http://www.pro.com/" target="_self">Home</a>
<a href="http://www.pro.com/products" target="_self" class="active">Products</a>
<a href="http://www.pro.com/solutions" target="_self">Solutions</a>
```

Other Page 2

```
<a href="http://www.pro.com/" target="_self">Home</a>
<a href="http://www.pro.com/products" target="_self">Products</a>
<a href="http://www.pro.com/solutions" target="_self" class="active">Solutions</a>
```

Comment: thank you but I think I found my answer now

Comment: If the solution I gave you in the comments above worked, would it be alright if you accepted my answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UbVVH/1/

Comment: it removes the class when new link is clicked on great but the new link needs to be the active color now

Comment: @dyscool You didn't mention that initially. I've edited, the jsfiddle with your new request.

Comment: my apologies, that is exactly what is needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }

})
```

Comment: yes the default page is the active link color yellow when entering the site but when the user clicks on another link which it's target to self the new current page has the active color yellow and the default page "home" is no longer yellow but white like the rest of the links normal color.

Comment: Guys, I think this is an HTML issue, not a JQuery one. The page is reloading the CSS every time a user clicks a link, which is 'undoing' the OP's JQuery.

Comment: Wow, I guess I was the one that was confused :S Lol

Comment: it is removing the JQ code, I tried the code this code and stil no luck but by it self it works

Comment: @dyscool Have you tried putting the class `active` on each page nav and removing the JQuery?

Comment: no, I should try that, give me a second

Answer (score 0):

Well if you click on a link, I'm guessing it's going to open a new page, so the active link gets reset on every page load. So what you want probably want to do is check if you're on the current page for each link.

So maybe in php:

```
<a href="http://www.pro.com/" target="_self" class="<?php echo ($page === 'home' ?  'active' : ''; ?>">Home</a>
```

If you want to do pure JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var path = window.location.pathname.toString().split('/')[0];

    $("a.active").removeClass("active");
    $("a." + path).addClass("active");

});
```

Make sure your links have a name to map to based on the path:

```
<a href="http://www.pro.com/" target="_self" class="home">Home</a>`
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking...

Comment: thank you but I don't know php

Comment: check my edit, for pure JS example

Comment: I just tried the javescript code and it removed the default link color buy mouse click on the new link but the new link is not the active yellow color.